# Update primary key in one table which is foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that it's primary key is foreign key in 5 tables.I need to change the value of this primary key field.what's the query?

```
             Table1 >> fields: tbl1ID(pk, bigint),  Desc(nvarchar(50))
             Table2 >> fields: tbl2ID(pk, bigint),tbl1ID(fk, bigint),  Desc(nvarchar(50))
             Table3 >>....
             .
             .
             .
```

I've set  tbl1ID=1 and now i need to change it like this tbl1ID=100001,
but i cant because this field is related to another table.

is it possible to change all of them?

Comment: We need to see table structure to better understand which 'value of this primary key field' you need to change and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simply by temporarily setting foreign_key_checks=0 in
   your session.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
UPDATE TABLE_A INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.PKID = TABLE_A.PKID 
SET TABLE_B.PKID = 'NEW_VALUE', TABLE_A.PKID = 'NEW_VALUE'
WHERE TABLE_A.PKID = 'OLD_VALUE';
```

Another option is to configure the foreign key with the ON UPDATE
   CASCADE option so that if the primary key is updated on the parent
   table it will cascade to the child table